# Using ogr2ogr to convert PostGIS table to personal geodatabase

Tags: database, odbc, gis, postgis, ogr2ogr

I need to convert a PostGIS table to a personal geodatabase using ogr2ogr. I can convert tables to a shapefile without a problem but whenever I try to convert it to .mdb using the ODBC driver, I get an error. I have got the 64-bit GDAL version and also the 64-bit ODBC driver installed.

This is my command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ODBC" C:\users\[user]\file.mdb PG:"host=localhost user=[user] dbname=[db] password=[password]" "[tablename]"
```

This is the error I get:

```
ODBC driver failed to create C:\users\[user]\file.mdb
```

Am I using the right command to do this, or am I missing a driver or something?

Comment: To supplement @TommasoDiBucchianico's answer, you can always get ogr2ogr capacity to read and write a format using the command `ogrinfo --formats`, then looking for your target format, i.e. [PGeo](http://www.gdal.org/drv_pgeo.html), `-> "PGeo" (readonly)`. It's possible that some day, the PGeo driver may support write, so if you just run this command, you'll know whether your build of ogr2ogr will allow for reading and writing of a supported format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. The ODBC is currently a read-only driver and cannot create databases.

From http://www.gdal.org/drv_odbc.html:

> Currently the ODBC OGR driver is read-only, so new features, tables
>   and datasources cannot normally be created by OGR applications. This
>   limitation may be removed in the future.